# Mongodb array field size limit

Tags: mongodb

Which is the limit of a mongodb array field?

subdocuments have a limit of 4mb-16mb(it depends of the version). Does an array has the same limits?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only limit is the document size. Whatever Document (or ReferenceDocument) contains the array cannot exceed that size. See [limits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/).